# 301 redirect for entire site except for subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have setup a sitewide 301 redirect in my .htaccess as follows

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^.* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I wanted to exclude subdomains (support, blog) from being included in this redirect. So I add the following RewriteConditions

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=support.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=blog.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^.* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This works totally fine. However I wonder if there is a better way to specify the exclusion for all subdomains (not WWW) in just 1 RewriteCond statement (instead of a separate RewriteCond for each subdomain)

I have a few more subdomains and plan to add some more. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: FYI - Apparently the browser caching the failed redirects is a known issue - "http://superuser.com/questions/609859/how-to-get-chrome-to-stop-caching-a-redirect-even-after-clearing-cache". Clearing the cache didn't address the issue for me. But then I passed a query parameter e.g. "http://blog.example.com/?temp=1" as suggested in the answer.. That took care of this.. Thought someone else will find this useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response anubhava! Unfortunately it doesnt work and when I try one of the subdomains, it redirects me to the https version of the homepage with the following error - "This is probably not the site you are looking for!
You attempted to reach blog.example.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as www.example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious..."

Comment: Much better. But I still have a problem with one of my subdomains. One works, one still gets the redirect. Maybe there is a problem on my end. Thanks!

Comment: Test that in a different browser since code should work with any subdomains now.

Comment: I was thinking that too. It works on a browser that I hadnt used before. But the ones that I had and had the redirect error are continuing to exhibit the problem. Seems like a browser caching issue. I tried to clear cache for the day.. That didnt work in Chrome. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it worked on a browser that you hadn't used before then it is definitely local browser caching issues. Try clearing all cache and restarting the browser.

Comment: I just tried that.. Doesnt work.I think I probably need to exclude the subdirectory from the redirect too. The subdomain is pointing to a directory in my domain. So I wonder if I need to exclude the directory as well. Any suggestions

Comment: Actually `demo.ezhomeheating.com` also works. I just opened it in my browser and **it did not goto https** Your browser has still not cleared the old cache.